# angular2 injecting service to a pipe

Tags: angular

Does anyone know how to injecting service to a Pipe in angular2?  I've got an example in [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mi0oG2kHvSfpfndMpqdL?p=preview)

So currently the service is doing nothing.  I've put the service in the constructor of the pipe, and put the Http in the Provider of app.  Instead I got an error saying

```
ChangeDetectionError {_wrapperMessage: "No provider for ConnectionBackend! (MyPipe -> MySe…Backend) in [Hello {{name | MyPipe}} in App@2:10]", _originalException: NoProviderError, _originalStack: "Error: DI Exception↵    at NoProviderError.BaseExc…ularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.8/angular2.dev.js:11284:19)", _context: _Context, _wrapperStack: "Error: No provider for ConnectionBackend! (MyPipe …gularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.8/angular2.dev.js:12682:27"…}
```

I'm not really sure what else I need to do.  I'm using angular2 beta 8.  Help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/oNlNePV9lCHbzGHeOKWu?p=preview)

You needed to provide `HTTP_PROVIDERS` in order to inject `Http` into `MyService`.

`MyService` also needed to be decorated with `Injectable()`.

Comment: this does solve my problem.  But when I try to implement the same in my project, it still doesn't work.  Apparently though after I delete the service and re-create it with different name, it works.  So i guess something wrong with angular2 (i'm using beta 3) or something wrong with the compilation part.  But at least this thing work.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You should add http providers:

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

providers: [MyService,HTTP_PROVIDERS]
```

I have fixed your plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sFdlOAmGXlC6B8WMiydp?p=preview).